# Does statement of Implicit Function Theorem imply that level set is a curve?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

According to the  Implicit Function Theorem ($2$ dimensional case):

> if $F:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ function defined on the open set $U$ and $(x_0,y_0)\in U$ such that $F(x_0,y_0)=0$ and $F_y(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$, then for some neighbourhoods $I,\,J$ of $x_0,y_0$, respectively there is a $C^1$ function $f:I\to J$ such that
> $f(x_0)=y_0$  and $F(x,f(x))=0$ for all $x\in I$.

In othet words, the  Implicit Function Theorem gives us conditions for a curve to be a graph of a function (locally).

Let $S=\{(x,y)\in U:F(x,y)=0\}$ be the zero level set of $F$. This level set is non-empty, since $(x_0,y_0)\in S$.

My question is: how are we sure that $S$ is really is a curve? For example, for $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, we have $S=\{(0,0)\}.$

Does condition $F_y(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$ imply somehow that $S$ is (indeed) a curve?

Or should we add this on the statement of the theorem? (which I think not...)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Yes, the nonvanishing of the gradient (of a $C^1$ function) at a point implies that the level set of the function passing through that point is a $C^1$ curve.

Comment: I see. Since $F_y(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$ and $F_y$ is continuous on the open set $U$, then for some neighbourhood $V$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ we have $F_y\neq 0$. Is this the right path towards the desired result?

Comment: You have to actually go through and understand the proof of the Implicit Function Theorem. It is a nontrivial theorem. The idea is that what works in linear algebra (non-vanishing gradient means you are looking at a non-trivial linear map) gives you a good local approximation to what's going on in the non-linear case.

Answer (score 1):

At a point $(x_0,y_0) \in F^{-1}(0)$ such that $F_y(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$, the IFT gives us a $C^1$ function $f:I\rightarrow J$ such that
$$ F^{-1}(0) \cap (I\times J) = \{(x,f(x)):x \in I \}.$$
Therefore within $I \times J$, $F^{-1}(0)$ may be represented by the $C^1$ curve
$$ \gamma: I \rightarrow I\times J, \quad \gamma(x) := (x,f(x)).$$
It follows that around any point $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $DF \neq 0 \iff F_x \neq 0 \text{ or } F_y \neq 0$, there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ and a $C^1$ map $\gamma: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the image of $\gamma$ is $U \cap F^{-1}(0)$. This is a definition of a one-dimensional $C^1$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (also known as a curve).

By the classification of one-dimensional manifolds, $F^{-1}(0)$ must topologically be a disjoint union of circles and lines.