# Does the implicit function theorem if it holds give a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or in $\mathbb{R}^3$)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Prove that the equations $\begin{cases}e^x+2e^{y}+e^z=4\\
x+y+z=0\end{cases}$ define a curve in space and the curve doesn't cross itself.

I let $z=-x-y$ and define $f(x,y)=e^x+2e^y+e^{-x-y}=4$.

My idea is to show that the graph of $f$ is a curve that doesn't cross itself. Then projecting it onto the plane $x+y+z=0$ will be a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that also doesn't cross itself. That the graph of $f$ is a curve can supposedly be shown by the implicit function theorem. If I haven't understood the following incorrectly [Does statement of Implicit Function Theorem imply that level set is a curve?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318705/does-statement-of-implicit-function-theorem-imply-that-level-set-is-a-curve?rq=1)

We have that $f_x=e^x-e^{-x-y}$ and $f_y=2e^y-e^{-x-y}$. These are zero only when: $\begin{cases}
e^x=e^{-x-y}\\
2e^y=e^{-x-y} \end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}-2x=y\\
\ln 2+2y=-x\end{cases}$.

The first equations has solutions $(x,-2x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and putting it in the second yields $\ln2=3x$ which gives the critical point $\left(\frac{\ln2}{3},\frac{-2ln2}{3}\right)$.

Since $f\left(\frac{\ln2}{3},\frac{-2ln2}{3}\right)\neq 4$ by the implicit function theorem the graph of $f$ is a injective curve(it doesn't cross itself).

Does the implicit function theorem actually give a curve? Consider $x^2-y^2=2$, the critical point for this equation is $(0,0)$ but the "curve" is a hyperbola. Now with the above in mind, projecting the hyperbola onto the plane gives two split curves in $\mathbb{R^3}$, is this still considered a curve and if not how can I be sure in my solution?

Edit: Not cross itself means no self-intersection. I don't know anything else this is a question from my exam in calc 3.

The solution given (it literally says advice on how to solve it).

Let  $f(x, y, z) = e^x + 2e^y + e^z$
och $g(x, y, z) = x + y + z$. We see that $x=z=y=0$ is a solution, thus the suspected curve contains atleast a point. We have that $\nabla f(x,y,z,)=(e^x,2e^y,e^z)$ and $\nabla g(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$. The vector product of the gradients is then $\nabla f \times \nabla g=(2e^y − e^z, e^z-e^x,e^x-2e^y)$. This vector is 0 if and only if $e^x=2e^y=e^z$. If $(x,y,z)$ is such a point with $g(x,y,z)=0$ then $x=z=(1/3)\ln2$ and $y=-(2/3)\ln2$. Then $f(x,y,z)\neq 4$. **This shows that $\nabla g$ and $\nabla f$ thever are parallel if $g(x,y,z)=0$ and $f(x,y,z)=4$ and therefore by the implicit function theorem a curve in space**.

Comment: The implicit function theorem does not ensure injectivity (only *local* injectivity). Otherly said: you did *not* prove that the curve does not cross itself.

Comment: I'm curious: how do we formalise "without crossing itself"? Do we mean, there is a C^1 bijection $[0,1]\to f^{-1}(4)$?

Comment: Possible, or more generally replacing $[0,1]$ by any type of interval or by a circle, like in  [this definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Topological_curve) of a "simple curve"? But now I am not so sure of my first comment. Isn't it clear from the OP that we have a submanifold of $\Bbb R^3$? I am lost. @FShrike Wasn't connectedness the only remaining problem?

Comment: @AnneBauval I am not sure. Did you mean, simple connectivity? because that would detect any loops due to a crossing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations already proved that these two equations define a submanifold of dimension $1$ of $\Bbb R^3$ (hence a "curve" that *doesn't cross itself*). (Incidentally, your edit results, though by another approach, in essentially the same concrete calculations.)

Your remaining doubt (when you spoke about the hyperbola and *two* split curves) was: does this submanifold really deserve the name of "curve", i.e. is it [*connected*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) (equivalently: is it the continuous image of *only one* interval or circle)? This question can be solved by the following extension of your calculations.

Letting $s=e^x,t=e^y>0,$ your equation $e^x+2e^y+e^{-x-y}=4$ becomes
$$ts^2+2t(t-2)s+1=0.$$
Given $t>0,$ this quadratic equation admits real solutions $s$ iff $t^2(t-2)^2-t\ge0$ i.e. iff $0\le t(t-2)^2-1=t^3-4t^2+4t-1=(t-1)(t^2-3t+1)$ i.e. iff $\frac{3-\sqrt5}2\le t\le1$ or $t\ge\frac{3+\sqrt5}2.$
These two solutions $s$ are then of the same sign (since their product is $\frac1t>0$). Their sum being $2(2-t),$ they are $>0$ iff
$$\frac{3-\sqrt5}2\le t\le1$$
and on this interval, they are two continuous functions of $t,$ which coincide only at the endpoints of the segment.

Therefore, your subset of $\Bbb R^3$ is a [simple closed curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Topological_curve).

Comment: Thanks but how did u get that $s$ is positive iff $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\leq t\leq 1$

Answer (score 2):

As already noted implicit function theorem is useless here.

We have that $f(x,y,z)=e^x+2e^{y}+e^z$ is a strictly convex smooth function (the Hessian matrix is diagonal with positive terms $e^x$, $2e^{y}$, $e^z$ along the diagonal) and therefore the level set $S=\{(x,y,z):f(x,y,z)\leq 4\}$ is a strictly convex smooth set. Then the intersection of $S$ with the plane $x+y+z=0$ is a strictly convex plane set. The intersection is not empty because it contains $(0,0,0)$.

Now the given the equations
$$\begin{cases}e^x+2e^{y}+e^z=4\\
x+y+z=0\end{cases}$$
are satisfied by the points of the boundary of such strictly convex plane set which is a [convex curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_curve). Any convex curve is simple (it does not cross itself): see for example Theorem 2.6.2 at p. 47 of these [notes](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Eanderson/mat362-spr15/petersen.pdf).

[image]

Comment: It didn’t seem apparent from that Wikipedia article that convex curves should be simple. Is there an easy explanation? Probably, but my visual intuition is bad

Comment: @FShrike I edited my answer with a picture and a reference